# Plugin problem on Zeppelin using Dataproc

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc, data-processing, dataproc

I am working with Dataproc and trying to save my notebooks on GCS and GitHub using the correct variables. But it is not working.

I am using Zeppelin component.

I got this error:

```
INFO [2020-07-23 19:54:59,790] ({qtp684874119-16} PluginManager.java[loadNotebookRepo]:60) - Loading NotebookRepo Plugin: org.apache.zeppelin.notebook.repo.GCSNotebookRepo
WARN [2020-07-23 19:54:59,791] ({qtp684874119-16} PluginManager.java[loadNotebookRepo]:68) - Fail to instantiate notebookrepo from classpath directly:org.apache.zeppelin.notebook.repo.GCSNotebookRepo
WARN [2020-07-23 19:54:59,791] ({qtp684874119-16} PluginManager.java[getPluginClassLoader]:181) - PluginFolder /usr/lib/zeppelin/plugins/NotebookRepo/GCSNotebookRepo doesn't exist or is not a directory
```

A check inside the master and the folder plugins doesn't exist.

Anyone can help me? How to install or configure this plugins?